# Overriding constraints

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am having some trouble overriding constraints in my testbench.
In my sequence I am doing the following:

```
    `uvm_do_with(req, {trans_kind == WRITE ;
                       address == 40'hc0_0000_0000;
                       mask_mismatch_error == 1;
                       bus_error_type == SCB_BUS_ERR_NONE;
                       }) //this line sends the transaction
```

And in my sequence item:

```
    constraint c_mask_mismatch_error_disable_map8 { (cfg_h.is_map8 == 1) -> (mask_mismatch_error == 0); }
```

The log file is giving this warning:

> ncsim: *W,SVRNDF (source location/line): The randomize method call
>   failed. The unique id of the failed randomize call is 86.
>
> Observed simulation time : 79492842 PS + 14
>
> ncsim: *W,RNDOCS: These constraints contribute to the set of
>   conflicting constraints: }) //this line sends the transaction 
>   (
>   (mask_mismatch_error == 0); }  (source location/line)
>
> ncsim: *W,RNDOCS: These variables contribute to the set of conflicting
>   constraints:
>
> state variables: cfg_h.is_map8 (1) [source location/line]
>
> rand variables: mask_mismatch_error [source location/line]

I don't understand why this type of override is not possible. What can I do to be able to override the constraint from the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` clause of a call to `randomize` is only used to add constraints; it cannot override them. The proper OOP way to override a constraint is to extend your transaction class and declare a constraint with the same name in the extended class.

Your other option is to turn the constraint off using

```
req.c_mask_mismatch_error_disable_map8.constraint_mode(0);
```

If you do that, you can no longer use the `umm_do_with macro, which many people recommend against using anyways.

Comment: Another option is to declare the constraint that you have as part of the sequence item as a `soft constraint`.